# Li's are not left aligned, Works as block level element

Tags: html, css

I have certain amount of dynamic `<li>` elements in my web page. I have some specified width to its parent i.e to `<ul>`. My use case  is to float each `<li>` tag to be left aligned to each other, And to be hidden if they reach their parent width. But `<li>` tags works as block level elements. It works fine if width is removed to parent tag. But i need width to the parent since i want to hide all child nodes once it reaches certain width. Refer the code which i tried [here](https://jsfiddle.net/santhoshkumar14/5bnmgnxc/).

```
     <ul class="tabsheet_sht">
      <li class="actives">Sheet1</li>
      <li>Sheet2</li>
      <li>Sheet3</li>
    </ul>
    .tabsheet_sht {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:0
}
.tabsheet_sht li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: I don't get what you want to do exactly! can you explain more clearly?

Comment: Open my fiddle remove width from ul tag. You can see all li tag will be left aligned. I want to achieve the same with the fixed width property to ul tag. Got it

Comment: the 100px width is too narrow for three items to be beside each other, if you made the width to be 300px it will work

Answer (score 2):

The below code should work. Add `white-space: nowrap;` to `ul`

```
.tabsheet_sht {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```